# Java - Unexpected behaviour from String.replace()

Tags: java, string

I am implementing my own scripting language as a side-project, and in the language variables are accessed by $[variable name]. However, when I use String.replace() to replace (for example) $myvar with myvar's value (eg 'My variable') with this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  
{  
    System.out.println(replaceVars("$myvar"));  
}  

public static String replaceVars(String source)  
{  
    String[][] varNames = new String[][]{new String[]{"myvar", "This is a variable"}, new String[]{"anothervar", "This is another variable"}, new String[]{"yetanothervar", "This is yet another variable"}};  
    String result = source;  
    for(String[] s : varNames) result = result.replace("$" + s[0], s[1]);  
    return result;  
}
```

Output: **$myvar**

What is going on?

Comment: Works for me...output is `This is a variable`

Comment: You should use a Map to hold your varname/bar value pairs

Comment: The original question had `static` missing on the `replaceVars` method.

Comment: The code in the project uses a HashMap, and it works as described in the question

Comment: I suspect you've written out your input by accident or something similar because the code, as posted now is correct and gives the correct result.

Comment: In this instance, it is pretty clear that you are expecting to get 'This is a variable' as your output. But for future questions, it it often helpful to answerers if we know what your expect to happen and not just what is happening.

Comment: Worked backwards through _every single part_ of my code and found the problem. Every time the interpreter read a line of code, it created a new instance of the class that holds variables. Sorry for wasting everyone's time, I'll try and be more thorough with debugging before posting a question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The (original) given code doesn't compile:

```
Main.java:7: non-static method replaceVars(java.lang.String) cannot be referenced from a static context
    System.out.println(replaceVars("$myvar"));
                       ^
```

... unless `replaceVars` is declared `static`.  Then it works as expected.

Comment: `replace` only takes a `char` so not sure how it works at all http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29

Comment: @0A0D replace can take CharSequences: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29

Comment: An overloaded `replace` takes a `CharSequence`, and `String` implements `CharSequence`.

Comment: I never knew that! thanks

Comment: @condorcraft110 But running that code does exactly what you expect, it returns "_This is a variable_"

Comment: Is everyone else testing using Java 6? People are quoting JDK6 javadoc links and I am using JDK7.

Comment: @condorcraft110: Shouldn't matter.. this stuff is backwards compatible.

Comment: @condorcraft110: Here is the java 7 ref: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29

Comment: Just thought it might be a difference with the way String.replace() is handled in JDK6 and 7, but it would seem not

Comment: To the people who say 'it works for me', the unexpected behaviour is that the output is literally `$myvar`, not `This is a variable`

Comment: Well, evidently thats not the case with the code you posted. This is a localized problem.

Answer (score 0):

As some comments say: works for me.

However, what you've not asked for is advice for your side-project in terms of implementation. Try processing "$myVar $myVars $myVarIsALongVariableName" - you'll probably rather want to do it right and do proper tokenizing etc.

IMHO this is, on another level, the unexpected behaviour. Use the other answers for solutions to your root problem. Also, double check that you're running exactly this class and that it's properly compiled, e.g. by changing the code for main to

```
System.out.println(replaceVars("edited: $myvar"));
```

Answer (score -1):

That's alright. It's doing what you've written.

1. `result == "$myvar"`
2. `"$myvar"` is replaced by `"This is a variable"`
3. symbol `$` is no longer present in `result`, so no replacements happen furthermore.

P.S. I'm just wondering if another commentators actually realize what's happening? No special chars or another stuff, just go by algorithm in your head please. Think before you post.

[Prooflink](http://ideone.com/RfGOTY)

[This code works](http://ideone.com/282hDw)